# Как экранировать одинарные кавычки?

Tags: postgresql

Выполняю запрос:

```
SELECT ' for=\'213\' '
```

Пишет:

```
ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "213")
LINE 1:     SELECT ' for=\'213\' '
                           ^
В операторе:

    SELECT ' for=\'213\' '
```

Comment: `select 'aa ''aa''   ';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо удваивать кавычки, как верно замечено в комментариях к вопросу:

```
SELECT ' for=''213'' ';
```

Или же [`escape string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) (требует явного указания на возможное содержание `escape` последовательностей)

```
SELECT E' for=\'213\' ';
```

Так же есть возможность вовсе не извращаться с кавычками, а использовать синтаксис строковых литералов `Dollar-quoted String` (там же в мануале)

```
SELECT $$ for='213' $$;
SELECT $anystring$ for='213' $anystring$;
```

Если же данные приходят от пользователя через приложение - то используйте `prepared statements` (или его эмуляцию вашей библиотекой доступа) и тогда вас экранирование не беспокоит вовсе.

Answer (score -3):

Кавычки экранируют 'кавычками'

Есть легкодоступная [документация](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/plpgsql-development-tips.html)

Разве плохо [гуглить](https://toster.ru/q/161003)?

Не канон, но вы также можете использовать апостроф WHERE a = `  b = ' 5 '  `